# Failed to authorize rights (0x1) with status: -60007

Tags: ios, xcode7, gitlab-ci

Trying to run an iOS unit test via GitLab-CI (multi runner on OS X) I am getting this error and then the build hangs:

`Failed to authorize rights (0x1) with status: -60007`

Anybody got it working? Or is that a bug in connection with Xcode 7.3?

Comment: It has been confirmed that Xcode 7.2 didn't have this issue. Also it does not have to do with code signing, because iOS unit tests don't require it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was running into the same problem with Jenkins and I had a build step that ran "open -a simulator" prior to running the unit tests. (I think I had read somewhere that this would open the simulator in a way that got around Jenkins running headless).

I was banging my head against it so I redownloaded Xcode 7.2.1 to verify it worked still and used xcode-select to switch versions, then I switched back and saw the problem still appeared in 7.3. I had noticed that a problem in 7.3 appeared to be that multiple simulators were getting opened when I rand the build.

Finally I removed the "open -a simulator" command and it seems to work. I still have one jenkins build that fails to sense when the unit tests finish running, but I haven't had a problem getting the tests to run. The build that still hangs does not swap the app delegate for a separate testing app delegate. (something like this: http://qualitycoding.org/app-delegate-for-tests/) So I'm hoping that could be the issue. Also note that my projects that only test libraries never exhibited bad behavior, they were always able to run the tests.

That's as far as I've got so far. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the agent. I had a similar issue with GoCD CI.
If you are launching your CI agent via LaunchDaemons you should see the given warning but if you launch your CI agent via normal shell prompt it should work as intended. At least I was able to solve my issue with the given thing.